# Extending and reexporting an imported TypeScript namespace

Tags: typescript, namespaces

In one of our projects we are importing a package that exports a bunch of color values, which we would like to extend and reexport. This has so far been done with plain old JS objects:

`theme-library/colors.js`:

```js
export const Colors = {
  error: '#f00',
  info: '#00f',
  success: '#0f0',

  axes: {
    x: '#f44',
    y: '#4f4',
    z: '#06f',
  },
};
```

`app/colors.js`:

```js
import { Colors as BaseColors } from 'theme-library/colors';

export const Colors = {
  ...BaseColors,

  done: '#0f8',
  selected: '#fc0',
};
```

Now that we're transitioning to TypeScript, we thought that it would be the right choice to convert these to a namespace, like this, which works in the library:

`theme-library/colors.ts`:

```
export namespace Colors {
  export const error = '#f00';
  export const info = '#00f';
  export const success = '#0f0';

  export const axes = {
    x: '#f44',
    y: '#4f4',
    z: '#06f',
  } as const;
}
```

But then we don't know what the proper way would be to extend these values in the source of the app. Spreading isn't valid, and I can't seem to figure out whether there is some other viable way of including all the members of a namespace in another one. Since I wouldn't mind extending the original namespace instead of creating a new one either, I considered namespace merging as well by simply importing `Colors` with it's original name and creating another one with the same name, but it [doesn't seem to work](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30141). (`"Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'Colors'.`)

`app/colors.ts`:

```
import { Colors as BaseColors } from 'theme-library/colors';

export namespace Colors {
  // None of these work:
  // ...BaseColors;
  // export * from BaseColors;
  // export { Colors } from 'theme-library/colors';

  export const done = '#0f8';
  export const selected = '#fc0';
};
```

I have tried reading around, and as far as I can see, this does not seem to be possible, but please tell me if my conclusion is wrong! If this is indeed not doable, then I would be interested in alternative approaches that we could take!

Comment: why not just export `Colors` with `export const Colors = { ... } as const`?

Comment: I was also considering falling back to a regular object. Maybe this is not the right use for a namespace at all? 

Comment: I personally discourage the use of namespaces in non-declaration files. They are generally not needed. They can be useful to declare untyped code which exposes global constructors. In your case, a regular object would suffice, with `as const` you preserve intellisense and prevent mutations. If you want to create a type for the object you can use `{...} satisfies ColorsType`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `export` as a namespace:

```
// a.ts
export const red = '#f00'
export const blue = '#00f'
// b.ts
export * from './a.ts'
export const blurple = '#40f'
// c.ts
export * as Colors from './b.ts'
// use.ts
import * as Colors1 from './b.ts'
import {Colors} from './c.ts'
```